# siunitx: limit the width of a table header

Tags: tables, siunitx

The decimal-aligned column of numbers I need to typeset has a very long header.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{E}{S[table-format=3.4, table-alignment=right]}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{E}
  \toprule
  {Very very long header}
  \midrule
  123.4567
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The example typesets as:

| Very very long header |
| --- |
| 123.4567 |

I need to limit the header width, so that it typesets with automatic line breaks:

| Very very long header |
| --- |
| 123.4567 |

Usually it can be done by using a paragraph

```latex
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\raggedright}p{3em}}
```

but I haven't found such an option in `siunitx` documentation. `table-fixed-width` doesn't enable line breaks but rather makes the header overflow.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Made compilable.

Comment: Perfect! Nice question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use your `N` column in the header like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{E}{S[table-format=3.4, table-alignment=right]}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\raggedright}p{3em}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{E}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{N}{Very very long header}\\
  \midrule
  123.4567\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```